# How do I make a link between the items in two different arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have these two arrays:

```
var Names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'];
var Ids   = ['1'   , '2'    , '3'   , '4'   ];
```

Also I have this variable:

```
var name = 'ja';  // to search in the Names array
```

I search `name` variable in the `Names` array as follow:

```
var MatchesNames = Names.filter(function(x){
                                  if(x.indexOf(name) >= 0) return x    
                         }).slice(0,4);   // slice() makes limit the results
```

The **output** of above code is:

```
alert(MatchesNames);
//=> jack,jack
```

As you see there is two duplicate names *(which have different ids)* .. Now I need to pull their ids out from `Ids` array. How can I do that? I guess I need an object but really I don't know how can I use an object in this case.

I want this **output**:

```
//=> jack(1),jack(3)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you only extract the names, then you can't necessarily link back to the index of those names and therefore the index of the IDs.  Unless you *assume* they are in order, then you're just running the same filter again... so why bother?   You should use objects instead of indirectly related arrays.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes exactly I should use objects, but how? I cannot implement it using objects ...

Comment: To use objects you would need to change how you generate the `Names` and `Ids` arrays. Is it possible for you to do that?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure I get your mean correctly but I think the answer is yes ... Actually I'm trying to create a [people-suggestion] on textarea.. exactly like this textarea which when I write `@{letter}` it suggests me a few people .. Now I need to their ids to ping them .. How access them ? *(as you see, two separate array has some problem with duplicate names)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Array index as id, and process it like:

```
var names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'];
var ids   = ['1'   , '2'    , '3'   , '4'   ];

var name = 'ja';

var result = [];

var zippedArray = names.map(function (e, i) {
    return [names[i], ids[i]];
});

zippedArray.map(function(element, index) {
    if(element[0].indexOf(name) >= 0) {
        result.push( element[0] + "(" + element[1] + ")" );
    }
});

console.log(result.toString());
// jack(1), jack(3)
```

Comment: Where is `Ids` array? In reality they aren't `1`, `2`, .., they are like this *(without specific order)* `52332`, `325421`, ..

Comment: Just two question? 1. why did you pass `index` in this `.map(function(element, index) {` ? I think that is useless. Am I right?  2. Can I use `filter` instead of `map` in that line I pasted?

Comment: @stack `index` is not needed with `map`. I forgot to remove it. And no idea how to solve it with `filter`. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate the name with the id, you should really use an object; otherwise you will have to **assume** that the id array and names are in the correct order, but it would be difficult to guarantee.

```
var people = [
  { name: 'jack', id: 1 },
  { name: 'peter', id: 2 },
  { name: 'jack', id: 3 },
  { name: 'john', id: 4 }
];
var name = 'ja';
var matchedPeople = people.filter((person) => person.name.includes(name));
var matchedIds = matchedPeople.map((person) => person.id);
```

You could also incorporate Ramda/Lodash to compose these functions

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this.

```
var Names = [{name: 'jack', id: 1}, {name: 'peter', id: 2}, {name: 'jack', id: 3}, {name: 'john', id: 4}];
var chars = 'ja';

var MatchesNames = Names.filter(function(x) {
  if(x.name.indexOf(chars) >= 0) {
    return x;
  };
}).slice(0,4);

MatchesNames.forEach(function(person) {
  console.log(person.name + '(' + person.id + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Approach with an [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a result array with objects.

```js
function find(o, s) {
    var r = [];
    o.names.forEach(function (a, i) {
        if (~a.indexOf(s)) {
            r.push({ id: o.ids[i], name: a });
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var Names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'],
    Ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    result = find({ ids: Ids, names: Names }, 'ja');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write(result.map(function (a) { return a.name + '(' + a.id + ')'; }).join(','));
```

Comment: @stack If this is the answer that best solves your problem then you should select it as the answer (not just upvote it).  I think there are better answers below though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [documentation for `.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), there's an option to call with the array index.

(It also returns true/false, not the actual value, so current usage is wrong, but a side issue).

This way, you can get an array of the IDs that match, at the time they match:

```
var Names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'];
var Ids   = ['1'   , '2'    , '3'   , '4'   ];

var name = 'ja';

var MatchesIds = [];

var MatchesNames = Names.filter(function(x, i){
    console.log("Check: " + i + " : " + x)
    if(x.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
      MatchesIds.push(i)
      return true  
    }
})  

console.log(MatchesNames)
console.log(MatchesIds)
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkuntaup/

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `reduce`:

```js
var Names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'];
var Ids = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];


var search = name => Names.reduce((r, n, i) =>
  n.indexOf(name) > -1 ? (r.push([n, Ids[i]]), r) : r, []);

results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(search('ja'));
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a professional but this may help. By the way you'll have to make some retouches.

```
var Names = ['jack', 'peter', 'jack', 'john'];
var Ids   = ['1'   , '2'    , '3'   , '4'   ];

function fakeZip(arr1, arr2) {
  var ret = new Object;
  for (var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
    ret[arr2[i]] = arr1[i];
  }
  return ret;  
}

var newobj = fakeZip(Names, Ids);
JSON.stringify(newobj);
/*
{"1":"jack","2":"peter","3":"jack","4":"john"}
*/
function lookFor(el, obj) {
  res = []
    for(key in obj) {
      if(obj[key]== el ){
        res.push(key)        
      }
    }
  return [el, res];  
}

lookFor("jack", newobj)

/*
jack,1,3
*/
```